# Word order of participial and nonparticipial adjectives

Tags: word-order, participles

I am interested in whether there is any correlation between the word order of NP modifiers and their morphology, which could be purely adjectival or participial. First off, nonparticipial adjectives like *shaven* or *open* can occur both to the left and to the right of the nominal head (1).

> (1a) A man carefully shaven
>
> (1b) A carefully shaven man
>
> (1a´) The doors recently open
>
> (1b´) The recently open doors

The related participial forms *shaved* and *opened* can also occur both to the left and to the right of the nominal head (2).

> (2a) A man carefully shaved
>
> (2b) A carefully shaved man
>
> (2a´) The doors recently opened
>
> (2b´) The recently opened doors

The nonparticipial adjectives also appear in the complement of *picture*-nouns: (3a) refers to a picture that shows a man who is carefully shaven. And in this context they can also occur to the left of the nominal head (3b) (note that (3b) entails that it is the man in the picture that is carefully shaven, not the picture itself). Similar observations apply to the other two examples.

> (3a) A picture of him carefully shaven
>
> (3b) A carefully shaven picture of him
>
> (3a´) A picture of the doors recently open
>
> (3b´) A recently open picture of the doors

**Now the interesting part.** My impression is that the order with the participle on the right is OK (4a) but the one with the participle on the left is not (4b), at least in the reading in which the participles modify the things in the picture. I feel (4b) and (4b´) entail absurdly that the picture is shaved and opened (respectively), that is, we are forced to take the participles here as modifiers of *picture*, not *him/the doors.*

> (4a) A picture of him carefully shaved
>
> (4b) A carefully shaved picture of him
>
> (4a´) A picture of the doors recently opened
>
> (4b´) A recently opened picture of the doors

Would you guys say this is a fair assessment of the data? I'm not a native speaker so I keep second-guessing myself.

Comment: Please note that  **ɴᴏᴛ ᴀʟʟ** “non-participial” adjectives can freely appear on either side of the nominal head.  Some adjectives can appear only to the left but not the right because they are **attributive only** (e.g., *live, elder, eldest, chief, main, principal, sheer, utter, mere,* plus *very* as adj. not adv.), while other adjectives can appear only on the right but not the left because they are either **predicative only** (e.g., *answerable, asleep, alone, ablaze, afraid, aloof, aware, unaware, fond*) or, more rarely, even **postpositive only** (e.g., *galore, elect, regnant, akimbo*).

Comment: (3b), (3b´), (4b), and (4b´) are all absurdist.

Answer (score 3):

1. "The doors recently open" can only be conceived elliptically as " The doors *that were* recently open", but this ellipsis does not seem to be recognized, perhaps because of the proximity with " The doors recently opened", which is readily given an unambiguous sense. It seems that the unique choice is the unellipted form.
2. "The recently open doors" — The conveying of a stative situation by means of an adjective so managed in the phrase does not seem to belong to current English. Here again, only the past participle can be used, and this is so as to convey the idea of an action instead of that of a state.

- The recently open*ed* doors

3. The second construction (3b - a carefully shaven picture of him) is not possible: the only interpretation is that of a picture that is shaven, which is nonsense in normal contexts.The third and the fourth fare no better.
4. Only the first and the third of this fourth lot of constructions are meaningful; the other two are nonsense.

Comment: Examples like "A naked picture of John," "Those blonde pictures of my ex-girlfriend," "Empty pictures of previously full rooms" are widely attested, where the prenominal adjective modifies not the head but the of-phrase. Perhaps the adverbs in (3-4) make them sound off to you? It'd be strange if one could have "a naked picture of NP" but not e.g. "an open picture of NP".

Comment: @Zoltan Surprising, I've never seen that, it must be the result of rather new practices ; in the extreme I can only reckon with some of those constructions as poetic constructions, and at that I am rather sceptical as to their poetical value.

Comment: Not all **postpositive** adjectives are merely **predicate** adjectives whose linking copular verb has gone missing thanks to so-called [tag:whiz-deletion], which I believe is what you mean here by elision. For example, a *president elect* is not a "president who is ❌elect" (which is not grammatical). More importantly, you don't strictly **need** to assume an elided WHIZ element here to construct a reasonable syntax tree for these sentences.

Comment: @tchrist I am aware  that assuming the "elision" of a whiz element is not the only possibility; here is for instance a case—there are quite a few more of that sort, you're certainly familiar with them—where no simple ellipsis explains the postposition: "[rivers navigable](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Noun_Phrase_in_the_Generative_Perspectiv/njc_EoeePKIC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22rivers+navigable%22&pg=PA297&printsec=frontcover)".

Comment: @Zoltan Take care not to focus too much on “pictures of” due to that construction’s special semantic transfers via genitives: *naked pictures **of John*** are not the same as *naked pictures **of John’s***. The first refers to pictures of John naked which are of unknown ownership, while the second presumably refers to pictures of someone else naked which John happens to own.

Comment: @LPH Another postpositive example that cannot be explained by whiz deletion: *I don’t care to see a picture of **John naked**.* :)

Comment: @Zoltan : I’m surely not going to search *a naked picture of John* to test your usage claim... but if anyone were to say that, it would be understood as *a “naked picture” of John*. Like *a cubist painting of John*. A genre. The adjective modifies the noun.